# Python with CGI - handle ajax

Tags: python, ajax, cgi

I'd like to:

1. Send request from the browser to a python CGI script
2. This request will start some very long operation
3. The browser should check progress of that operation every 3 seconds

How can I do that?

Comment: JS on the client-side, a Python script which will query the operation somehow on the server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the server side, you should probably look into some background queue / job runner of sorts, otherwise your request will be blocked once the long operation starts (depends on your server). I hear [Celery](http://celeryproject.org/) is pretty good. On the client side, do some polling every x seconds that checks the job status. If you're feeling adventurous, you could experiment with websockets, although they're not supported *natively* in all browsers (you could use 3rd party extensions to try and accomplish cross browser support).

Answer (score 1):

You could do this -

1. Use Javascript to check progress every 3 seconds.
2. Your Python script hit at anytime should give the progress at that instance. It should essentially act as state-machine. You need a server here or maybe the progress is stored on some file.

But having a server is the way to go... 
Maybe the long running process stores the progress in a MySQL table.

Hope this helps...